# Phusion Passenger with Ruby 1.8 and 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

How would I go about running two separate Rails applications using Phusion Passenger with one using Ruby 1.8.x and the other using Ruby 1.9.x ?  I'm running Redmine which isn't Ruby 1.9.x compatible, and the other application is a home grown app.

I'm using Apache 2.2.x with Passenger 2.2.4.

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up running Nginx with Passenger and Ruby 1.9 on port 80, and then proxying off my other virtual hosts to Apache 2.2 on port 8080 with Passenger and Ruby 1.8.  Win!

Answer (score 4):

Just a little late but I found this thanks to Google: [Phusion Passenger & running multiple Ruby versions](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) Must be the necromancer in me.

Comment: [Phusion passenger running multiple versions](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PassengerRuby](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) directive.

Comment: heya, umm according to the docs, PassengerRuby can only be specified once, and doesn't seem to be allowed in virtual host configs ?

Comment: Ops, you are right. I didn't notice it was a global server configuration.

Comment: Not anymore since Phusion Passenger 4. I can be configured per vhost/location.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger supports multiple Ruby interpreters as of version 4.0.0 (February 2013). The PassengerRuby config option has been made a per-virtual host option, so you can customize your Ruby interpreter on a per-application basis.  See [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) for details.