# phusion passenger and ruby 1.9.1 is it working already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, passenger

i have a production and a development machine, both running ubuntu 8.10 and both are running the latest phusion passenger. as i am using ruby 1.9.1 on my local development machine on osx, i wondered if people out there are already using phusion passenger with ruby 1.9.1 or even 1.9.2 already?
if so, please tell us your setup!

furthermore, is ther a way to run both ruby 1.8.7 (ree) and 1.9.1 with phusion passenger on apache?
thanks for any pointers, i could not find any hints on this anywhere...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it's officially supported since some 2.2.x release for which I can't remember the exact number. It was written in the release notes. The past few 2.2 releases have only continued to add 1.9-related bug fixes. The upcoming 3.0 release will officially support 1.9.2 as well (though this doesn't imply that 1.9.2 doesn't already work).

You can't run two Ruby versions simultaneously yet but it's on the todo list.

Comment: As Hongli develops passenger, I think this is the definitive answer

Comment: that's great news! i will try out ruby 1.9.1 with passenger as soon as possible!

Comment: in this stackoverflow thread, a person mentions that running one ruby version on passenger and another one on nginx does the trick for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291143/phusion-passenger-with-ruby-1-8-and-1-9